# jQuery modification needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have some tabs to behave as shown [here](http://www.keepandshare.com/userpics/d/a/v/e/8528sky/2014-11/sm/tabs-39983986.jpg?ts=1416433877).  The following codes do the job, but upon click the Tab2, the content of Tab1 still shows on the right panel and if I click the items/links on Tab2, it displays below the content of Tab1.  I need a proper onClick event so that previous Tab's content gets cleared once another Tab is clicked.  Here are my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTab(selected, total)
{
  for(i = 1; i <= total; i += 1)
  {
    document.getElementById('tabs-' + i).style.display = 'none';
  }

  document.getElementById('tabs-' + selected).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<div id="tabs-1" style="display: none">Tab1 info 1 content</div>
<div id="tabs-2" style="display: none">Tab1 info 2 content</div>
<div id="tabs-3" style="display: none">Tab1 info 3 content</div>

<ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li id = "tabs1" onclick = "showTab(1,3)">Tab1 info 1</li>
  <li id = "tabs2" onclick = "showTab(2,3)">Tab1 info 2</li>
  <li id = "tabs3" onclick = "showTab(3,3)">Tab1 info 3</li>  
</ul>
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Why did you tagged [tag:jQuery] if you aren't using it?

Comment: Maybe he wants to learn jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this very easily with jQuery using `.siblings()` to hide the other content sections not active:

**JS**

```
$("ul.side.bar.tabs li").click(function(){
   var grabName = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#tab-"+grabName).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab-one" style="display: none">Tab1 info 1 content</div>
<div id="tab-two" style="display: none">Tab1 info 2 content</div>
<div id="tab-three" style="display: none">Tab1 info 3 content</div>

<ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li class="one">Tab1 info 1</li>
  <li class="two">Tab1 info 2</li>
  <li class="three">Tab1 info 3</li>  
</ul>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b97y4L0y/)

Be sure to wrap your code in a ready function in the `<head></head>` section:

```
<head>
   //link to jquery

   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("ul.side.bar.tabs li").click(function(){
            var grabName = $(this).attr("class");
            $("#tab-"+grabName).show().siblings("div").hide();
         });
      });
   </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but for some reason it wont display the contents at all now!

Comment: @Dave_O did you wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(function(){}` and os jQuery loaded?

Comment: @jmoore009 I am a newbie.  I have jQuery loaded but I didn't get what you meant by "wrap you code" :(   I just placed your JS in place of what I have.  Am I suppose to place it elsewhere?

Comment: @Dave_O updated my anwser. Just be sure to load jquery before your code

Comment: Thank you @jmoore009 !  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that it's not working for me.  I'll keep playing around with it till I get it working. I'll accept your answer though.  Thanks again.

Comment: @jmoore009  any thought/suggestions on how to implement this on a wordpress page by any chance?  Thank you!

Comment: @jmoore009 got it worked out, but I still have one problem and that is the content of previous tab wont clear when a new tab is clicked (i.e Tab 2 in the image I provided).  Thanks again.